# How to execute transaction operation according to tradingview index？

Tags: pine-script

I just study the pine script , and I saw the indicators in the public indicators. There were long or short instructions in the trade map, but they disappeared in a while. Why? Who can help me? Thank you

Comment: What kiind of instructions are you talking about?